# Unable to insert data into table with foreign key in oracle11g

Tags: oracle11g

```
CREATE TABLE  Client_master (
    Client_no varchar(6) PRIMARY KEY, 
    Name varchar(15) NOT NULL,
    City varchar(15),
    Pincode number(8),
    State varchar(15),
    Bal_due Number(10,2), 
    CHECK(Client_no LIKE 'C%'));

INSERT INTO 
Client_master(Client_no,Name,City,Pincode,State,Bal_due)
VALUES('C00001','Ivan Bayross','Bombay','400054','Maharashtra',15000);

1 row created.

CREATE TABLE  Sales_order(
    Order_no varchar(6) PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES Client_master (Client_no),
    Order_date date, 
    Client_no varchar(6),
    Dely_type char(1) DEFAULT 'f', 
    Billed_yn char(1), 
    Salesman_no varchar(6),
    Dely_date date, 
    Order_status varchar(10), 
    CHECK(Order_no LIKE 'O%'), 
    CHECK(Order_status IN ('inprocess','backorder','cancelled')), 
    CHECK(Dely_date>Order_date));

INSERT INTO Sales_order(Order_no, Order_date, Client_no, Dely_type, Billed_yn, Salesman_no, Dely_date, Order_status) 
VALUES('C19001','12-jan-96','C00001','f','n','S0001','20-jan-96','inprocess');

INSERT INTO
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02291: integrity constraint (SYSTEM.SYS_C007155) violated - parent key not
found
```

Please help me insert data into `Child` table. 
What's this  `SYSTEM.SYS_C007155` error? Why this error message "parent key is not found"?

Answer (score 0):

The `parent key not found` is because you have a foreign key in your `sales_order` table which is pointing to the `client_master`, and there is no matching key value - exactly what it says. But it's because you've done something odd:

```
Sales_order(Order_no varchar(6) PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES Client_master (Client_no)
```

You've made the `order_no` the primary key for this table, but **also** made it a foreign key to the `client_no` on the other table. Your insert uses `order_no` of `'C19001'`, which doesn't match the `client_no` you previously inserted into the parent table.

You almost certainly wanted `sales_order.client_no` to be a foreign key to `client_master.client_no`, so you would have the `references...` against *that* column:

```
CREATE TABLE  Sales_order(Order_no varchar(6) PRIMARY KEY,
  Order_date date,
  Client_no varchar(6) REFERENCES Client_master (Client_no),
  ...
```

You have a further problem as the check constraint you have against the `order_no` is `CHECK(Order_no LIKE 'O%')` but as mentioned the value you're putting in is `'C19001'`, which doesn't match the pattern. Presumably you meant the insert to be for `'O19001'`; if not then the constraint is defined incorrectly. I actually hit that check constraint before the primary key constrain in 11gR2, so you may just have changed that while posting the question.

You can look in the `user_constraints` and `user_cons_columns` views to see what a constraint is doing, but you'll find it easier if you [name your constraints](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/SQLRF/clauses002.htm#CJADJGEC) instead of letting Oracle [give them default names like `SYS_C007155`](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/SQLRF/clauses002.htm#SQLRF52193):

> Specify a name for the constraint. If you omit this identifier, then Oracle Database generates a name with the form SYS_Cn. Oracle stores the name and the definition of the integrity constraint in the USER_, ALL_, and DBA_CONSTRAINTS data dictionary views (in the CONSTRAINT_NAME and SEARCH_CONDITION columns, respectively).

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE  Client_master (
  Client_no varchar(6),
  Name varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  City varchar(15),
  Pincode number(8),
  State varchar(15),
  Bal_due Number(10,2),
  CONSTRAINT Client_master_pk PRIMARY KEY (Client_no),
  CONSTRAINT Client_master_chk_no CHECK(Client_no LIKE 'C%'));

INSERT INTO Client_master(Client_no,Name,City,Pincode,State,Bal_due)
VALUES('C00001','Ivan Bayross','Bombay','400054','Maharashtra',15000);

1 row inserted.

CREATE TABLE Sales_order (
  Order_no varchar(6),
  Order_date date,
  Client_no varchar(6),
  Dely_type char(1) DEFAULT 'f',
  Billed_yn char(1),
  Salesman_no varchar(6),
  Dely_date date,
  Order_status varchar(10),
  CONSTRAINT Sales_order_pk PRIMARY KEY (Order_no),
  CONSTRAINT Sales_order_fk_client FOREIGN KEY (Client_no)
    REFERENCES Client_master (Client_no),
  CONSTRAINT Sales_order_chk_no CHECK (Order_no LIKE 'O%'),
  CONSTRAINT Sales_order_shk_status CHECK
    (Order_status IN ('inprocess','backorder','cancelled')),
  CONSTRAINT Sales_order_chk_dates CHECK(Dely_date>Order_date));

INSERT INTO Sales_order(Order_no, Order_date, Client_no, Dely_type, Billed_yn, Salesman_no, Dely_date, Order_status)
VALUES('O19001','12-jan-96','C00001','f','n','S0001','20-jan-96','inprocess');

1 row inserted.
```

If you do have a violation, e.g. with your original `order_no` value, you'd see a more useful message:

```
INSERT INTO Sales_order(Order_no, Order_date, Client_no, Dely_type, Billed_yn, Salesman_no, Dely_date, Order_status)
VALUES('C19001','12-jan-96','C00001','f','n','S0001','20-jan-96','inprocess');

ORA-02290: check constraint (YOUR_SCHEMA.SALES_ORDER_CHK_NO) violated
```

so you can have a better idea which constraint is violated, and what that means, without having to loo in the data dictionary. `SALES_ORDER_CHK_NO` is easier to interpret than `SYS_C007155` Use names that make sense for you of course.

You can name [inline constraints](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/SQLRF/clauses002.htm#CJAGIICD) too:

```
CREATE TABLE  Client_master (
  Client_no varchar(6) CONSTRAINT Client_master_pk PRIMARY KEY,
...

CREATE TABLE Sales_order (
  Order_no varchar(6) CONSTRAINT Sales_order_pk PRIMARY KEY,
  Order_date date,
  Client_no varchar(6) CONSTRAINT Sales_order_fk_client REFERENCES Client_master (Client_no),
...
```

but it might be clearer and easier to maintain with them all grouped together at the end.